# $_POST is only returning submit button value and none of the other input box data

Tags: php

`print_r($_POST)` returns: `Array ( [saveBasicInfo] => Save )`
As title states, when i hit submit nothing in the input text boxes is actually sent. The onlything that is being sent is the value of the submit button.

Any ideas why?
I have identical code on another page and it is sending form info fine.

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?user=" . $userInfo['Id']; ?>" >

    <label for="StudentNumber">Student Number</label>
    <input id="StudentNumber" type="text" value="<?php echo $userInfo['StudentNumber']; ?>" />


    <label for="Pawprint">Pawprint</label>
     <input id="Pawprint" type="text" value="<?php echo $userInfo['PawPrint']; ?>"  />



    <label  for ="LastName">Last Name</label>
    <input  id="LastName" type="text" value="<?php echo $userInfo['LastName']; ?>"/>


    <label for="FirstName">First Name</label>
    <input id="FirstName" type="text" value="<?php echo $userInfo['FirstName']; ?>"  />

    <label for="MiddleName">Middle Initial</label>
    <input id="MiddleName" type="text" value="<?php echo $userInfo['MiddleName']; ?>"/>

    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Save" name="saveBasicInfo"/>
   </form>
```

Comment: U need to put the attribute `name` in every input...

Comment: You can could remove the `name` from the submit button, to prevent sending this pair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to needing a `name` attribute for the elements that you want to send to the server, I see one other thing to note.

[According to w3c standards](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/button.submit.html), input types should be data being inputted. A button of any kind, should be a button element. If it is a submit button, then you should use the button element and specify `type = 'submit'`.

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

your inputs are missing the ''name'' attribute

Answer (score 1):

Your `input` fields are missing the  `name` attribute.

```
<input name="..." value="..." />
```

Answer (score 0):

where is the "name" attribute in your inputs ?

[Note: Only form elements with a name attribute will have their values passed when submitting a form.](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_name.asp)